# Binary structures description in documentation

Tags: c++, binary, protocols, structure

I would like to describe the C / C++ binary structures that our program receives through its network socket in our user documentation, but I'm not very experienced in representing that data correctly and beautifully.

I like the way the DVB protocol is described in their technical documentation:
[image: dvb structures description]

But I don't know of an authoring tool that would allow me to do that easily for me (with syntax help and so on).

Do you know of tools or languages that are specifically made for that kind of task?
I know of ASN but I find it hard to read for a user-oriented spec.

PS: I'm not sure this belongs to SO and not SuperUser or another stackexchange site. If you know better, don't hesitae to migrate the question.